# Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/stuff: 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to learn how to save an object into a Mongoose DB. Even though it looks like I have done everything correctly, I keep getting a `Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/api/stuff: 400 Bad Request` in the browser that shouldn't be there. This error doesn't mean much to me. What's wrong with my request?

I am probably missing something.

```
app.post('/api/stuff', (req, res, next) => {
    delete req.body._id;
    const thing = new Thing({
        ...req.body
    });
    thing.save()
        .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Objet enregistré !'}))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
});
```

Complete app.js code :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const Thing = require('./models/thing');

mongoose.connect(
        'mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-lrbfc.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
        { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
    ).then(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB réussie !'))
    .catch(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB échouée !'));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
        'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'
    );
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api/stuff', (req, res, next) => {
    delete req.body._id;
    const thing = new Thing({
        ...req.body
    });
    thing.save()
        .then(() => res.status(201).json({ message: 'Objet enregistré !'}))
        .catch(error => res.status(400).json({ error }));
});


app.use('/api/stuff', (req, res) => {
    const stuff = [
        {
            _id: 'oeihfzeoi',
            title: 'Mon premier objet',
            description: 'Les infos de mon premier objet',
            imageUrl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/11/18/56/camera-4267692_1280.jpg',
            price: 4900,
            userId: 'qsomihvqios',
        },
        {
            _id: 'oeihfzeomoihi',
            title: 'Mon deuxième objet',
            description: 'Les infos de mon deuxième objet',
            imageUrl: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/06/11/18/56/camera-4267692_1280.jpg',
            price: 2900,
            userId: 'qsomihvqios',
        },
    ];
    res.status(200).json(stuff);
});

module.exports = app;
```

thing.js :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const thingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    imageURL: { type: String, required: true },
    userId: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);
```

EDIT :

If I console log `req.body` and `error` I get this :

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Listening on port 3000
Connexion à MongoDB réussie !
{
  title: 'sadfsaf',
  description: 'sdf fds sag asdf',
  price: 12300,
  imageUrl: 'sadf',
  userId: 'userID40282382'
}
Error [ValidationError]: Thing validation failed: imageURL: Path `imageURL` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (/mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/scottish_nodejs/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:61:24)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:563:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:221:10)
    at formatWithOptions (internal/util/inspect.js:1693:40)
    at Object.Console.<computed> (internal/console/constructor.js:272:10)
    at Object.log (internal/console/constructor.js:282:61)
    at /mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/scottish_nodejs/backend/app.js:36:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  errors: {
    imageURL: MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `imageURL` is required.
        at new ValidatorError (/mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/scottish_nodejs/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:29:11)
        at validate (/mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/scottish_nodejs/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1061:13)
        at /mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/scottish_nodejs/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1115:11
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/scottish_nodejs/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1070:14)
        at /mnt/c/Users/Shadow/Development/scottish_nodejs/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:2303:9
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11) {
      message: 'Path `imageURL` is required.',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'imageURL',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'Thing validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError'
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Thing model code to the question and the request.body you use to save it? Also why do you have this code in the end of the main file? `module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', thingSchema);`

Comment: your entry `/api/stuff` defined as post... and you didnt attach the code that calls your service. if (for instance) you are trying to call your service with `GET` method (instead of `POST` you will get an error)

Comment: I've just added the Thing model.

The last line you reffered to was a copy/pasting error of mine. I've corrected it as well.

Comment: req.body is an array and you are trying to delete property req.body._id. You should delete _id from each object by iterating.

Comment: We need to use what is inside the req.body?  Can you console.log(req.body) and put it to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have required `imageURL` field in the schema definition. But in the req.body you use `imageUrl`, so mongoose gives that error.

If you send your req.body like this, it will work:

```
{
    "title": "sadfsaf",
    "description": "sdf fds sag asdf",
    "price": 12300,
    "imageURL": "sadf",
    "userId": "userID40282382"
}
```

Comment: I sloppy typing mistake again. gos!

Thank you very much (even if it's forbidden).